# Releasing CUDA memory Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-leaks, cuda, gpgpu

I have noticed that memory allocated in the GPU is not released.
I used the following command:

```
A=gpuArray.randn(1e4);
gpuDevice
```

FreeMemory: 3.3336e+09

```
A=A*2
```

FreeMemory: 2.5336e+09

Looks like MATLAB allocated memory for A*2, but did not release the memory for A. I don't see how I can release the memory that is no longer in use. The problem is even worse for `A=A*A'` as it seems that MATLAB allocates even more memory (probably for A') and does not release it.
I found on the internet, that this is a known bug (or a similar bug?) that was solved in MATLAB 2013b (see http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/954239), but I am using MATLAB 2014a. I also installed the zip file from the link, but it did not help.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure that you are seeing the relevant decimals of the free memory?

Comment: Yes. btw, when you repeat it twice (repeat A=A*2), then the amount of free memory does not decrease and it behaves fine.

Answer (score 2):

By running some code like the following:

```
d = gpuDevice;
A = gpuArray.rand(1e4);
freeMem = NaN(1, 11);
freeMem(1) = d.FreeMemory;
for idx = 2:11
    A = A * 2;
    wait(d);
    freeMem(idx) = d.FreeMemory;
end
plot(1:11, freeMem / 1e9, 'b-', ...
     [1 11], [d.TotalMemory, d.TotalMemory]/1e9, 'r-');
legend({'Free Memory', 'Total Memory'});
xlabel('Iteration');
ylabel('Memory (GB)');
```

You can see that MATLAB is not immediately releasing the memory, but neither is it holding on to it for ever:

[image: Plot of free memory against iteration]

You will also find different behaviour if you make `A` larger. My GPU has ~6GB of RAM, and if I make `A = gpuArray.rand(16000)`, then I see that the memory appears to be released immediately.

By the way, the bug report you refer to is actually talking about host memory being irretrievably leaked, not device memory.

Are you actually running out of device memory in your algorithm?

Comment: In your example, the memory did not release. I'm aware to that if you do A=A*2 several times, then (after the first time) it will not allocate additional memory, but even in your example, the memory of A was not released. I'm getting out of memory, but the error appears is different and forces me to restart MATLAB. This happened on several GPUs running on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Yes the memory did release otherwise the graph would continue to show increasing memory being consumed as the loop progresses (that's what I was trying to show in any case). Also, if you clear `A` after the loop, the GPU gets back all its memory. Might I suggest you post a question that shows your actual problem? (What you're seeing here basically is an artefact of a memory management scheme).

Comment: I agree that some of the memory was released, but it still holds a memory twice as needed. Another example, if do: A=gpuArray.randn(5000); B=A*2; clear A; you will see that no memory was released, because B is somehow related to A.